# Geometric Interpretation of a Vanishing Covariant Derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, tensors, connections, lie-derivative

I find many instances where --- allowing a tensor defined on a hypersurface with components given by $T^\alpha$ and a basis given by $\textbf{S}_\alpha$ (where $\textbf{S}_\alpha$ are the orthogonal basis vectors on the hypersurface) --- if the tensor has a vanishing covariant derivative it can simplify equations greatly. Usually, I can tell that these tensors have significance in the geometrical layout of the problem, but I do not understand what "class" of tensors defined on a hypersurface have the following property:
$$\nabla_\beta T^\alpha=0$$
Can any of you help me understand the geometrical significance of under what circumstances a Tensor given on a hypersurface has a vanishing Covariant derivative defined on a hypersurface? Thanks Alot

Comment: That's what it means for the tensor field to be "parallel" or "covariant constant." For example, the Riemann curvature tensor has covariant derivative $0$ on a locally symmetric space (something like a sphere, Grassmannian, etc.). It does not necessarily mean that it is "constant," whatever that would mean, because it's not a scalar object.

Comment: Parallel with the covariant basis? Can you elaborate?

Comment: So I was speaking in more general terms, and referring to the entire tensor field, not to components with respect to a given basis. I guess in your case you're referring to a particular contravariant tensor field of rank $1$, given by $\sum T^\alpha \mathbf S_\alpha$, and saying its covariant derivative should be $0$ in every tangent direction. This builds in the derivative of the coefficients $T^\alpha$, but also the twisting of the frame $\mathbf S_\alpha$ as well. You will have vector fields that are parallel along all curves only if your manifold is flat.